# How can I get DateTime object from SQL Server 2008 in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

```
System.DateTime start_time = (System.DateTime)phones_.GetStartTime(callInfo.No[1].e164, callInfo.No[0].e164)[0][0];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think he is unable to cast it properly and this could be possible solution

```
DateTime dt= Convert.ToDateTime(phones_.GetStartTime(callInfo.No[1].e164, callInfo.No[0].e164)[0][0]);
```

Mr. Noro, you need to use `Convert.ToDateTime` function to cast it properly.

Comment: It doesn't help me. Is there other solutions?